# Distinguish the errorview with the same error in action fallback

Tags: error-handling, elixir, phoenix-framework

have an action in 2 controller that can return the same error. But in one action is html and in the other one is json.
How can i distinguish the view to render in action fallback?

Thanks

Comment: You could use `get_format(conn)` in the `call` function of your fallback plug. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 separate fallback controllers. One for APIs (JSON) and one for normal views (HTML) since you can define the fallback on a per-controller basis.

Something like:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Api.V1.UserController do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  action_fallback MyAppWeb.ApiFallbackController

  ...
end
```

And

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.UserController do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  action_fallback MyAppWeb.ViewFallbackController

  ...
end
```

That's how I did it in a recent project and it works quite well.